# How to pass an An Object array to a method

Tags: java

I have a Method called as getStrategy inside a class and its expecting an array as shown .

```
public static String getStrategy(Hand[] Hand)
{

}
```

And this is my Hand Object

```
public class Hand
{
  public char side;
}
```

On to my client , Please tell me how can i pass  this getStrategy method ??

I have tried this

```
Hand[] HandArray = new Hand[1];

HandArray.side = 's';

MyClassUtil.getStrategy(HandArray);
```

Please tell me if this si correct or not ??

Comment: `HandArray.side = 's';`: Your compiler will already tell you that this is wrong. Please include any compiler error messages with this or any future posts. These messages are usually very informative, and you will want to learn how to understand them. We can help.

Comment: Just think about this logically - does the array itself have a `side` field?

Comment: you have to declare a constructor in your hand class so you can do something like `HandArray[0] = new Hand('s');` and that parameter gonna initialize the side variable.

Comment: Also, replace `public static String getStrategy(Hand[] Hand)` with `public static String getStrategy(Hand[] hand)`

Comment: @Eng what is the difference? :)

Comment: @talnicolas `Hand` is a class name and the compiler will give you an error

Comment: oh ya hadn't noticed the capital h my bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well all but the middle line is fine (naming aside). Currently your middle line is trying to access an array as if it were a single object. You probably want something like:

```
Hand[] hands = new Hand[1];
Hand hand = new Hand();
hand.side = 's';

hands[0] = hand;
MyClassUtil.getStrategy(hands);
```

I would also strongly suggest *not* using public fields...

Comment: By @Jon Skeet's last statement, he is referring to the char field 'size'. It is usually much more appropriate to use protected here in this manner, since they are likely part of the same namespace. If you need public, create a private variable _size and use size as the public modifier, defining it like private char _size; protected char size {public get { return _size; }, set{_size = value}}.

Comment: Alternatively `side` could be made `public final` as long as it didn't need to be re-set. This would only be possible if the `Hand` constructor took a `char` as an argument of course.

Comment: @KublaiKhan: That would still be exposing an implementation detail (the field). I would normally only expose true constants (`public static final` fields of immutable types) as variables.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Interesting point about exposing implementation details - well taken.